# Accessing VPN resources in Windows guest from Linux host

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, virtualbox, vpn

I have a Ubuntu hosting a Windows XP box (using VirtualBox). The Windows XP box is connected to work using [Check Point VPN-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_Point_VPN-1). Essentially this enables me to go to my Windows box and do something like `ping comp-at-work` and it just works.

I would like to access the VPN resources from the Linux host though. The Windows guest is only there because the VPN client isn't working in Linux. If I could somehow `ssh` from the Linux host right into my computer at work (using remote desktop would also be great), that would save me a lot of round trips between my Linux host and the Windows guest.

Answer (score 2):

If your looking for a free option, just setup OpenVPN at work so you can connect from your Linux distro. Or you can check out some of the paid services like log me in

Comment: I work in a corporate environment... I have no control over the setup

Answer (score 1):

Is the VM's network using NAT or Shared networking?  Try changing it to NAT if it's not set already. This way the Window client will be routing requests appropriately, and requests to the VPN network should get sent across the VPN.

Comment: it's configured to NAT. are you saying it should just work?

Comment: It's a guess; I don't have the equipment to to test it out, but NAT means the host computer is responsible for routing traffic to the correct location; if NAT asks to communicate with an address on the VPN, I imagine the host computer should route it appropriately.